# Ubuntu 17.10 - Nokia 5 Android 7.1.2

Tags: nokia

I plug in the device, the icon is on my desktop and it goes blank.

[image]

Comment: Is your phone locked? If so, what happens if you unlock it?

Comment: The device is not lock and nothing changes. I tried everything(Charging mod, Photo transfer mod etc.). Another Android is working.
I found this(https://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/), but i cant install.

Comment: There is an 'USB Charging' mode and an 'USB mass storage device' mode in Android (not sure of the exact names). You possibly have to enable USB debugging in order to choose the USB connection mode.

Comment: Can you please translate "Klasör Bos" - is it "empty folder"?

Comment: - Translate: Folder is Emty -


I try with Usb debugging nothing change again.

Comment: What is the output of `mount` (typed in a terminal which you get by typing Ctrl-Alt-T) when the phone is connected?

Comment: Attached  Linux CD-Rom. The SD Card comes in when i eject and reconnect. I can open it and see the folders, but there is no Read and Write permission.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Nokia 5 (TA-1053) does not support real MTP mode without some kind of hacks. By default, it shows some kind of faked USB CD-ROM drive which only contains Windows and Mac drivers. Those drivers probably should do some kind of magic to hide the faked USB CD-ROM drive and show the real MTP Android device. I don't know what kind of magic Nokia 5 requires.